# How to select based on one to many relationship?

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

My table looks like:

```sql
create table user(
  user_id int,
  name varchar(10)
  );
  
  
create table orders(
  user_id int, 
  product varchar(255));
                  
insert into user(user_id, name)
values
    (1,'Chris'),
    (2,'Jon');
                  
insert into orders(user_id, product) values 
    (1, 'prod1'),
    (1, 'prod1'),
    (1, 'prod2'),
    (2, 'prod3');
```

I want to get all users which ordered `prod1`.
So the result table should look like this:

```
+---------+-------+
| user_id | name  |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | Chris |
+---------+-------+
```

It would be best if it is possible to do this with join's.
I tried something like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM user 
INNER JOIN orders ON user.user_id = orders.user_id 
WHERE orders.product = 'prod1' OR orders.product='prod2';
```

But it is not working for me, because there are duplicates.

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gVBzt9i16CTRcQLCPoBezP/2

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT user.*` instead of `SELECT *`

Comment: "It's not working because there are duplicates" isn't really a problem statement though, it's more an observation that says nothing about what you actually want the solution to be

Comment: There is a result table.

Comment: @Barmar I would hesitate to recommend "do a SELECT DISTINCT" because it'll generally teach someone "if you get duplicates, just clobber them out with DISTINCT" - it's typically not the right solution, it's just band aid, and massively wasteful of resources at that

Comment: @CaiusJard It's not always the solution, but it's the right thing for this question.

Comment: Either that or join with a subquery that uses `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Maybe, but I'd advocate redesigning the schema to disallow duplicates

Comment: You can also use `WHERE EXISTS...` or `WHERE user_id IN (...)` but MySQL doesn't always optimize these well.

Comment: @CaiusJard What do you mean? Why shouldn't the schema allow a user to have multiple orders?

Comment: As distincted by what? Put a counter on if you want to know how many times user has ordered prod 1; don't store another row with no extra info

Comment: He just wants to get the user ID and name, he doesn't want the order details. The user ID is being duplicated in the join because they have multiple orders.

Comment: NEVER use `SELECT *`. Instead, name and qualify only those columns you actually want returned - and if you want prod1 users, don't mention prod2

Answer (score 0):

I added to queries to the [DBFIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gVBzt9i16CTRcQLCPoBezP/4):
( and removed the `or product='prod2'`)

The first one show also the count of the products sold:

```
SELECT user.user_id,user.name, orders.product, count(*)
FROM user 
INNER JOIN orders ON user.user_id = orders.user_id 
WHERE orders.product = 'prod1' 
GROUP BY user.user_id,user.name, orders.product;
```

And, If you are not interested in the count, you can do:

```
SELECT user.user_id,user.name
FROM user 
WHERE user.user_id in (select user_id 
                       from orders 
                       where orders.product = 'prod1') 
;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct user.*
FROM user
INNER JOIN orders ON user.user_id = orders.user_id
WHERE orders.product = 'prod1'